# Hide a Shopify section based on users screen size using CSS

Tags: css, shopify

I would like help with code that will show a different slideshow section on Shopify based on the users screen size. I am using the code below which works great on a mobile device but on my laptop I see both slideshows.

What code do I need to add to hide the mobile slideshow when the screen size is above a certain amount of pixels?

```
   #shopify-section-mobile-slideshow {
      display: none !important;
    }
  @media (max-width: 450px){ 
    #shopify-section-slideshow {
      display: none !important;
    }
    #shopify-section-mobile-slideshow {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: the code you have should be sufficient. My guess is that you are missing an element, is the website public so you could share the link?

Comment: Hi @stanley its not public yet but the URL is: https://iron-mills1.myshopify.com/ password is corona

Comment: The code I have provided hides the original shopify slideshow section on my mobile but as I said on my laptop both are displayed.

Comment: try this, worked for me: #shopify-section-1586161998623 {
    display: none;
}

Comment: This worked thanks - I have included your code in the answer and referenced you!

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by @stenley -

Use inspector elements to ascertain the section ID

For me:

```
 #shopify-section-1586161998623 { display: none; }
  @media (max-width: 768px){ 
    #shopify-section-slideshow {
      display: none !important;
    }
    #shopify-section-1586161998623 { display: block; }

  }
```